# Failing to compile avr-libc sources on Ubuntu 13

Tags: c, ubuntu, gcc, compiler-errors, autotools

I have been following the instructions [here](http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/install_tools.html) to compile an avr cross compiler toolchain on my x86 PC. I had to do some searching on the step for compiling gcc because it was complaining about some missing dependencies, turns out there was a a script I could just run which downloaded the pre-requisites.

Now however, I am stuck on the step where I'm supposed to compile avr-libc. I get this error:

```
blah@blah-computer:~/avr/avr-libc-1.8.0$ ./configure --prefix=$PREFIX --build='./config.guess' --host=avr
checking build system type... Invalid configuration `./config.guess': machine `./config.guess' not recognized
configure: error: /bin/bash ./config.sub ./config.guess failed
```

From my googling of this problem, it seems there might be something wrong with my installation of autotools, and I actually remember seeing some warning about autotools when I was compiling gcc but as far as I could tell that step was actually successful.

Could anybody give me a good quick explanation of what autotools is and maybe help me fix my problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see why you would need to specify `--build` at all. Just set the environment variable: `CC=avr-gcc` (the AVR cross compiler), and use `--prefix=...` and `--host=avr` as before. AVR-libc will set the CFLAGS to the 'best' values as it builds each ISA version in the multi-lib.

However, if you want to specify `--build`, use the *backtick* characters rather than the single-quote characters to execute the script: **--build=`./config.guess`**

Comment: Why do I need to set the environment variable CC=avr-gcc, and what exactly does the --build flag do? I'm very new to building a toolchain, first one I've compiled myself.

Comment: @NickHalden - I'm not certain that `CC=avr-gcc` is absolutely required, or if the configure script looks for an AVR cross compiler - I suspect it doesn't. There's an overview of *triple targets* [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf.html#Specifying-Target-Triplets).